# Variable in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this code in Prolog... I use swi-prolog for ubuntu.

```
follows(ilias, petros).
follows(petros,ilias).
follows(petros, demos).
follows(demos,petros).
```

and I ask this 2 queries:

```
?- follows(petros,X),follows(X,petros).
X = ilias ;
X = demos ;
false.

?- follows(petros,makis),follows(makis,petros).
false.
```

and getting these two different outcomes. My trouble is that from what I know makis is a variable just like X. but prolog doesn't respond the same way and I can't understand why is that.

Thank you in advance for any answer!!!

Comment: `makis` is a constant while `Makis` is a variable.

Answer (score 2):

A *variable* in prolog is a string of upper-case letters, lower-case letters, digits and underscore characters that **starts** either with an **upper-case letter** or with an **underscore**.

So, you may use `Makis` instead of `makis`.